# Object Oriented D3 JS - How to select object?

Tags: javascript, oop, d3.js

Setting up my D3 project, which will have a number of shapes on the screen being animated (`Org` class).  I am trying to maintain an object-oriented paradigm, and take advantage of the D3 animations (https://jrue.github.io/coding/2014/lesson07/).

Consider the code below:

```
function test() {

    class Org {
        constructor(_width, _height) {
            this.width = _width;
            this.height = _height;
        }
    }
    var orgs = [];
    var canvas = d3.select('body')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', screen.width)
            .attr('height', screen.height);

    for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        var circle = new Org(Math.random()*screen.width, Math.random()*screen.height);
        orgs.push(circle);
        canvas.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', circle.width)
            .attr('cy', circle.height)
            .attr('r', 5)
            .attr('fill', 'pink');
    }

    for (var b = 0; b < orgs.length; b++) {
        circle.transition().attr('cx', 0); //DOES NOT WORK
    }
}
```

Obviously, the commented line throws an error because `transition()` belongs to D3, not my class.  How can I select these objects and animate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not very D3-*ish*, which makes it cumbersome to achieve your goal. Keep in mind, that D3 by its nature is about data-driven documents and, thus, [data binding](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data) is at its very core. It is essential to understand this concept to get the most out of this library. When refactoring your code accordingly, the solution becomes almost obvious.

That said, it always looks suspicious using for-loops when dealing with D3. Only rarely is there a need to put those loops to use as this is taken care of by D3's internal workings. Without breaking your OO-approach you can bind your `orgs` array to a selection and take advantage of D3 doing its magic:

```
var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
  .data(orgs)
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', d => d.width )
    .attr('cy', d => d.height )
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('fill', 'pink');
```

This will append circles to your selection corresponding to all `Org` instances in your `orgs` array which was bound to the selection using `.data(orgs)`. The above statement also keeps a reference to the selection containing all newly appended circles in the `circles` variable, which you can use for later manipulation.

This reference comes in handy, when doing the transition:

```
circles
  .transition()
    .attr('cx', 0);
```

Have a look at the following snippet which is equivalent to your approach, but does it the D3 way.

```js
class Org {
  constructor(_width, _height) {
    this.width = _width;
    this.height = _height;
  }
}

var orgs = d3.range(100).map(function() {
  return new Org(Math.random() * screen.width, Math.random() * screen.height);
});

var canvas = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', screen.width)
  .attr('height', screen.height);

var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
  .data(orgs)
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', d => d.width )
    .attr('cy', d => d.height )
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('fill', 'pink');

circles
  .transition()
    .attr('cx', 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

---

You might want to have a look at some tutorials about this concept for a more in-depth introduction:

1. [Three Little Circles](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)
2. [Let’s Make a Bar Chart, Parts I](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/), [II](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2) & [III](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3)
3. [Thinking with Joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)
4. [How Selections Work](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) (advanced)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps give them an id and select them with d3?

First give the circles an id:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        var circle = new Org(Math.random()*screen.width,    Math.random()*screen.height);
        orgs.push(circle);
        canvas.append('circle')
            .attr('id', "myCircle_" + x)
            .attr('cx', circle.width)
            .attr('cy', circle.height)
            .attr('r', 5)
            .attr('fill', 'pink');
    }
```

Then select them by id:

```
 for (var b = 0; b < orgs.length; b++) {
        d3.select('#myCircle_'+b).transition().attr('cx', 0);
 }
```